# Error ORA-01652 en Oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Estoy tratando de ejecutar la siguiente consulta `SQL`

```
select * from (with
        carlos_rojas as (
            select distinct 
                  M000.G300CTA as CUENTA
                , G300.G300NCTL  as NOMBRE
                , G006.G006TDOD  as TIPO_DOCUMENTO
                , C002.C002NDOC  as NUM_DOCUMENTO
                , G300.G300AGE   as COD_AGENCIA
                , G009.G009AGED  as AGENCIA
                , G008.G008PRON  as PRODUCTO
                , 0 AS disponible
                , 0 as saldo_final
                from MRCJ000 M000
                    inner join GSCF300  G300 on G300.G300CTA = M000.G300CTA
                    inner join CCLF002 C002 on G300.G300CLI = C002.C001CLI
                    inner join GTGF006 G006 on G006.G005TDOC = C002.C002TDOC
                    inner join VCVF002 V002 on G300.G300UUID = V002.V001UUID
                    inner join GTGF009 G009 on G300.G300AGE = G009.G009AGE
                    inner join GTGF008 G008 on G300.G300PROD  = G008.G007PROD
                    inner join USEJE000 U000 on U000.UIDEJE000 = M000.UIDEJE000 
                    inner join CNLF000  C000 on C000.CUUID000  = M000.CUUID000
                where C000.CUUID000 = '2' and U000.UIDEJE000 = '41'
        ),

        saldos_en_marcaje  as (
            select
                G300.G300CTA   as CUENTA
            from GSCF300 G300 
                inner join GSCF305 G305 on G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
                inner join MRCJ000 M000 on M000.G300CTA = G300.G300CTA
            and trunc(G305.G305FDIA) <= to_Date('2019/02/15', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
        )

        select 
            cr.CUENTA,
            cr.NOMBRE,
            cr.TIPO_DOCUMENTO,
            cr.NUM_DOCUMENTO,
            cr.COD_AGENCIA,
            cr.AGENCIA,
            cr.PRODUCTO,
            cr.DISPONIBLE,
            cr.SALDO_FINAL
        from carlos_rojas cr
            left join saldos_en_marcaje s on cr.CUENTA = s.CUENTA 
        where s.CUENTA is null)

union

select * from (with
        carlos_rojas as (
            select M000.G300CTA as CUENTA
                from MRCJ000 M000
            inner join GSCF300  G300 on G300.G300CTA = M000.G300CTA
            inner join USEJE000 U000 on U000.UIDEJE000 = M000.UIDEJE000 
            inner join CNLF000  C000 on C000.CUUID000  = M000.CUUID000
            where C000.CUUID000 = '2' and U000.UIDEJE000 = '41'
        ),

        saldos_en_marcaje  as (
            select
                   G300.G300CTA   as CUENTA
                 , G300.G300NCTL  as NOMBRE
                 , G006.G006TDOD  as TIPO_DOCUMENTO
                 , C002.C002NDOC  as NUM_DOCUMENTO
                 , G300.G300AGE   as COD_AGENCIA
                 , G009.G009AGED  as AGENCIA
                 , G008.G008PRON  as PRODUCTO
                 , G305.G305S02   as DISPONIBLE
                 , G305.G305S01   as SALDO_FINAL
                 , row_number() over (partition by G300.G300CTA order by G305.G305FDIA desc) NumFila
            from GSCF300 G300 
                inner join GSCF305 G305 on G300.G300UUID = G305.G301UUID
                inner join MRCJ000 M000 on M000.G300CTA = G300.G300CTA
                inner join CCLF002 C002 on G300.G300CLI = C002.C001CLI
                inner join GTGF006 G006 on G006.G005TDOC = C002.C002TDOC
                inner join VCVF002 V002 on G300.G300UUID = V002.V001UUID
                inner join GTGF009 G009 on G300.G300AGE = G009.G009AGE
                inner join GTGF008 G008 on G300.G300PROD  = G008.G007PROD
            and trunc(G305.G305FDIA) <= to_Date('2019/02/15', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
        )

        select 
            s.CUENTA,
            s.NOMBRE,
            s.TIPO_DOCUMENTO,
            s.NUM_DOCUMENTO,
            s.COD_AGENCIA,
            s.AGENCIA,
            s.PRODUCTO,
            s.DISPONIBLE,
            s.SALDO_FINAL
        from carlos_rojas cr
            inner join saldos_en_marcaje s on cr.CUENTA = s.CUENTA
        where s.NumFila = 1)
```

y me arroja el siguiente error:

> ORA-01652: no se ha podido ampliar el segmento temporal con 128 en el tablespace TEMP
>
> 1652. 00000 -  "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
>
> *Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
>              a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
>
> *Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
>              files to the tablespace indicated.

No entiendo la causa de este error y si existiera una manera de poder solucionarlo..

Comment: pareciera que te has quedado sin espacio, podria probar creando un nuevo datafile

Comment: Te quedaste sin espacio para tu tablespace TEMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Encontre una solucíon! Aumentar el `sort_area_size`.

Sin embargo como estamos manejando `11g` ya este parámetro existe solo por mantener la compatibilidad con sistemas anteriores donde acostumbraban aumentar el tamaño de esta variable para la sesión.

Para dar un solución definitiva se trabaja con `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET`

***Solución:***

Este valor se establece en el 20% del tamaño total de memoria asignada

En nuestro caso era 800MB y lo coloque a 1000MB.

**Instrucción:**

```
SQL> show parameter PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
==================================== =========== ==============================
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 0


SQL> alter system set PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET = 1000M;

System altered.

SQL> show parameter PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
==================================== =========== ==============================
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 1000M
```