# Oracle 12c: no se ha podido ampliar el segmento temporal

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con este error de `Oracle`.

AL ejecutar una consulta grande no sigue procesando y se para la consulta

> [Error] Execution (4: 3): ORA-01652: no se ha podido ampliar el
>   segmento temporal con 128 en el tablespace TEMP

Les agradezco

Comment: Lo que te indica es que tu tabla temporal TEMP se ha quedado sin espacio para ejecutar la consulta, lo que debes es ampliar dicha tabla

Comment: Significa que el tablespace TEMP se llenó por completo durante la ejecución de tu consulta. La solución pasa por hacerlo más grande (ponerle un datafile o datafiles adicionales) o replantear el tamaño de los resultsets que usas en tu consulta.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error ORA-01652 en Oracle](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287162/error-ora-01652-en-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

puedes corregirlo haciendo:

primero para validar la ruta y el nombre

```
select name from v$datafile;
```

ahora buscamos la ruta del `temp01.dbf` el nombre puede variar y la copiamos
 ahora bien si fuese `C:\oracle\app\oradata\zoom\temp01.dbf` agregaremos un segundo datafile con
`C:\oracle\app\oradata\zoom\temp02.dbf`

```
alter tablespace temp add tempfile 'C:\oracle\app\oradata\zoom\temp02.dbf' size 1g;
```